# Python: how to start an invisible python console from a python script under windows?

Tags: python, windows, popen

I need to start a python console from a python script under windows.
Output of this console must be written on a textbox.
I'm using subprocess 'cause python console can be python 2 or 3, depends on choice of user, so I can't use code.InteractiveConsole.
Now, i start python with subprocess.Popen, stdin=PIPE, stdout and stderr are two file subclasses where write methods print on my textbox.

```
class output(file):
  def __init__(self):
    super(output,self).__init__("out","wb")
  def write(self,data):
    MyTextBox.Text = data
out=output()
```

All ok.
p=Popen("python -i",stdin=PIPE,stdout=out,stderr=err)
err is an other class, same as output, but an other file.
Ok, p is a subprocess, but stdout and stderr are None.
Sure, I wrong something, but I don't understand!
Maybe I must use 4 variables? out_write and out_read for stdout and err_write, err_read for stderr?
Help!

Comment: the code example is fairly unclear, could you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't posted all source, but I solved with answer. Now I'm able to grab output and error from my invisible python console. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the command prompt window, pass the appropriate flags:

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
#si.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE 
subprocess.call('whoami', startupinfo=si)
```